# How to record the underlying CLI action for GUI clicks on Linux?

Tags: user-interface, command-line-interface

I often script things, which also can be done with a graphical user interface. To do it once, it's easy to use the gui. To do it often, it's much faster to use scripts.

(Almost) all gui applications use an underlying cli application. For example switching the desktop resolution most likely issues a xrandr call.

Or a gui click just changes some underlying configuration file, which is just as interesting.

Reading the cli documentation and figuring out the same result takes time. Can that be improved?

I mean, can I record the underlying CLI calls for any GUI clicks on Linux?

Answer (score 5):

> (Almost) all gui applications use an underlying cli application.

This is untrue. Most applications use calls to functions either in their own code or in some other library. Deleting a file in Nautilus does not run `rm(1)`, it calls `unlink(2)` (see `man 2 unlink`). Programs that make use of xrandr functions should use `Xrandr(3)` rather than `xrandr(1)`. Spawning another process to handle such tasks is slow, wasteful and ugly.

Still, you may be able to capture relevant details with [auditd](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/07/04/track-file-changes-auditd/).

Comment: Put better than I could have put it. You're absolutely right, more often than not these are API calls _within the source of the graphical program_ which interact with other parts of the system.

Answer (score 3):

A very valuable tool is strace.  This allows you to see what files are changing and what is being written when you give it the appropriate flags.

See: http://www.hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace.html

If the GUI is simply making calls to programs as suggested by other answers, you will see it.  If you're looking for network interaction between dbus and an application you will see that as well.  Access to socket files will be seen as well.

It's good to use netstat -nlp as well to find out what ports individual daemons are using as well so that you can easily track down the interactions.

If it's network traffic you're interested in, tcpdump is of course the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheap trick I once used to get insight into what parameters were passed to a CLI command:

create an *executable* script, in a specific location like `~/bin`, that prints out the command line parameters:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $@
exit 0
```

name it the same as the CLI executable you want to mimic. Now because it is possible to have two executables with the same name, bash will execute the first one it finds, in order specified in your PATH environment variable.

To wit, temporarily alter your PATH to include `~/bin` before any other path:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Now running the GUI application *within* the terminal with the altered PATH, will call your script instead of the original CLI executable. Your script will print out any parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking for, but sometimes I use this trick to understand what's happening behind the scenes. First, I start capture the output of `ps afxu` in a loop:

```
counter=0 ; while (true) ; do ps afxu > ps-afxu-capture-step-$counter ; echo "Capturing step $counter..." ; sleep 0.01 ; counter=$((counter + 1)); done
```

Then I `diff` the captured "frames" to see what changed:

```
for i in `seq 1 100` ; do diff ps-afxu-capture-step-$i ps-afxu-capture-step-$((i+1)) ; done > ps-afxu-capture-diff.txt
```

I used this trick just yesterday to try to **[understand what `mk4ht` was doing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75277/19518)**.

Uh, it's better if you run the first sequence of commands in a subdirectory of `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the problem from a not exactly proper level. What you call a "CLI app" is actually any software, that uses standard i/o streams without having a GUI. CLI app, as GUI-based app or web server is a frontend with some logic that does library and kernel calls. You may have an app that does use xrandr to change resolution. On the contrary, you might have an app that does that by using some library around X protocol, or app doing so using X protocol, or even an app, that does resolution change using kernel calls (here I am *mostly* referring to older kernels)!
You might be able to intercept messages to CLI apps in some way, as previous posters answered, but I doubt it's what you're referring to. You can't get every action tracked otherwise than using libraries to intercept work of the underlying libraries of software you'd like to test - and then you'd get list of library calls instead of CLI apps with arguments.